# Removing "noise" from a 1d list

Tags: python

I have a list with possible values of `1` `2` or `3`
On situations where there is a sequence of the same value, and one instance of another value within that sequence - I would like to "smooth" that sequence - so that the different value will become the same as the rest.

For example: 

`[2, 2, 1, 2, 2]`

Will become: 
`[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

My question is, if there is a mathematical "smoothing" function I can use here, and if so which one...

Thanks

Comment: Only if there is *one* different value? What happens with a list `[2,1,2,1,2]`? Or `[2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1]`?

Comment: There's no such function I can name, but it would be more or less trivial to write one. The problem is mainly picking noise from signal as @WillemVanOnsem mentioned.

Comment: Are you looking for a low-pass filter?

Comment: sounds like downsampling: https://skemman.is/bitstream/1946/15343/3/SS_MSthesis.pdf

Comment: More ambiguous: what should this function do with `[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]`? This appears to be a `1` in the middle of a sequence of `2`s, and also a `2` in the middle of a sequence of `1`s.

Comment: Probably not a low-pass filter. If the `1` was a `3` it should be removed. In Adam Smith's example the result should be: `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]`. The actual case is a bit more complex, I was looking for a general direction. Downsampling as suggested by @Uriel, after reading a bit - might be what I'm looking for... thanks

Comment: @YuvalA. https://github.com/devoxi/lttb-py python implementation, referenced by author's github, or https://github.com/javiljoen/lttb.py

Comment: What if there's an extra `1` at the end of my example? Does that now change to `[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`? Or should the filter act strictly left-to-right?

Comment: It's from left-to-right. In Willem Van Onsem example, it should be `[2,2,2,2,2]`. If there was an extra 1 or more, like `[2,1,2,1,1,2]` then the result would be `[2,2,2,1,1,2]`

Comment: It seems like you have to go through the list by for loop  the time consumed will be O(1). BTW what will happen to [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]?

Comment: For my purpose - it should stay like that. Only the middle values should be "flattened"/"smoothed" (not sure the right term here).